# How to make a TextView to take only IP address

Tags: android

I want to make a textview in my app to get the ip from user. I have set the input type to digits and decimal. The problem is that it takes only one dot where as the ip needs four dots. I don't want the users to see the alphabets on keyboard. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you really should try something and show the code you've tried so we can help you find where you might be making things wrong.

Well, I think this lib is a good start for you:

https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask

You can use any mask you need, look:

```
<br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    mask:mask="ccc.ccc.ccc-cc"
    mask:char_representation="c"
/>
```

You can also set the mask programmatically:

```
MaskedEditText editText = (MaskedEditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text)
editText.setMask("##/##/####");
```

As for the users not being able to see the alphabet keyboard, you can set the input type to number only:

> android:inputType="number"

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Everything is fine but i am generating the textview programmatically inside a AlertDialogbox can you please give me a hint on setting this mask:mask="ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc" property programmatically.

Comment: I've just edited my answer on how to do it. Get some time to read the documentation of the lib, it's really worth!

Answer (score 0):

First off-  you can never prevent the letters entirely.  All you can do is tell the keyboard to use NUMBER, and it can do whatever it wants in respect to that.  Most keyboards will at least show a number pad by default then, but there's no way to enforce whether the user can get to the alphabet keys or not.

Secondly-  you can do this.  Create a TextWatcher for that view, and capture the changes as they're entered.  Process each new letter to make sure it works as part of an IP address, and reject it f not (you can also use this as a chance to auto-insert the dots).